# Singularities on null capacity sets are removable — Wiener or Bouligand?

Tags: mathematics, discoveries, potential, wiener

A classical theorem on harmonic functions states that singularities of bounded harmonic functions are removable if the singular set is of null capacity. This theorem is sometimes attributed to Bouligand, and sometimes to Wiener. I have seen it proved in Wiener's 1924 paper, but I cannot find any source related to Bouligand. Can you please help me locate the original paper of Bouligand where it is proved, or a secondary source that claims Bouligand's priority?

Comment: Maybe because the name is spelled Bou*ligand*. See his expose [*Fonctions harmoniques* (1926)](https://eudml.org/doc/192545) that gives citations to earlier papers.

Comment: @Conifold: Thanks! I spelled the name correctly when I searched. The mistake was made only in this post.

Comment: @Conifold: As far as I can tell, there is no mention of the removable singularity theorem in this paper.

Comment: There is a list of 14 more at the end, I did not look.